# Changing Appearance of Master Page based on Content Page

Tags: asp.net

My Master Page has a heading with tabs.  The code looks something like:

```
<CT:Tab ID="tabHome" runat="server" Url="/index.aspx" Text = "Home" Highlight="true" />
<CT:Tab ID="tabFun" runat="server" Url="/fun.html" Text = "Fun"/>
<CT:Tab ID="tabBlog" runat="server" Url="/blog" Text = "Blog"/>
```

I can think of two ways to control which tab is highlighted from within a user control:

1. Have the user control implement an interface.  The master page can decide which tab to highlight based on which interface is implemented, or based on a method in the interface that returns a string.
2. In the `Page_Load` (or `Page_Init`) function, tell the master page (via FindControl or via a function in the Master Page) which control to highlight.

I don't really like either of these solutions.  Is there a clean way I could control which tab is highlighted from the control at design time (i.e., in the aspx file)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is:

1. Create an event delegate on the UserControl that passes a parameter indicating which user control to highlight
2. Handle this on the master page; so whenever the event is fired it chooses the correct tab to highlight based on the parameter passed
3. Fire the event on the user control Page_Init

A good start on events and delegates is at MSDN here: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This strikes me as way more complicated than just having the page implement an interface with a property that indicates which tab to highlight.